# What's the fastest way to draw to an HTML 5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, performance, html5-canvas

I'm investigating the possibility of producing a game using only HTML's canvas as the display media. To take an example task I need to do, I need to construct the game environment from a number of isometric tiles. Of course, working in 2D means they by necessity come in rectangular packages so there's a large overlap between tiles.

I'm old enough that the natural solution to this problem is to call BitBltMasked. Oh wait, no, an HTML canvas doesn't have something as simple and as pleasing as BitBlt. It seems that the only way to dump pixel data in to a canvas is either with drawImage() which has no useful drawing modes that ignore the alpha channel or to use ImageData objects that have the image data in an array.. to which every. access. is. bounds. checked. and. therefore. dog. slow.

OK, that's more of a rant than a question (things the W3C like tend to provoke that from me), but what I really want to know is how to draw fast to a canvas? I'm finding it very difficult to ditch the feeling that doing 100s of drawImages() a second where every draw respects the alpha channel is inherently sinful and likely to make my application perform like arse in many browsers. On the other hand, the only way to implement BitBlt proper relies heavily on a browser using a hotspot-like execution technique to make it run fast.

Is there any way to draw fast across every possible implementation, or do I just have to forget about performance?

Comment: What's bitbit?  I'm not exactly young, but don't know what it is.  I googled it, but found lots of random and unhelpful stuff.  More on topic, it sounds like your issue is that you have a game with a lot of action.  Does doing things like rendering the background and caching it help you?  I think maybe if you explained a little more detail of your design goals / constraints it might help.

Comment: thats an L, not a second i in bitblt, that will help alot in your googling :)  Here you go http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitblt

Comment: @Allen thanks! guess maybe I need new glasses!

Comment: IMHO, this seems pretty close to premature optimization. Try a small testcase first and benchmark that.

Comment: Feh. You say optimisation, I say prudence. We're talking about doing 100s of alpha blends a second when the real number that I need to do is zero. Alpha composition isn't cheap. Not to mention, what do I benchmark it against? The whole point is that I can't generalise about the performance of the API as given. I suspect some browsers on Windows will do this blazingly fast because directdraw gives them a consistent abstraction over hardware acceleration. On the other hand, I bet smartphones do this dog slow.

Comment: @aerik a bit blit is a method of drawing image data directly to display memory. It is a method used in your graphics hardware and low level device drivers.  With respect to the html5 canvas, there is no way to bypass the canvas and access the video memory directly.  The canvaspixelarray is an interface to this memory.

Comment: @ChrisDavies you are right: only higher-level operations are possible, no bitblt for you :)

Comment: `[...] drawImage() which has no useful drawing modes [...]` That's an old question, but now there is a `globalCompositeOperation` attribute to change the draw mode. It can be useful.

Comment: Well.. canvas is "family friendly" :) Those bound checks needs to be there. Mmm, brings back memories of the blitter co-processor on the Amiga (in the very old days that is; and everything *but* bound checks :-] Guru meditations eventually became your friend). drawImage() is the closest thing though. Render once off-screen, reuse render (draw once and displace it to move it around) and only redraw gaps. My 2 cents.

Answer (score 6):

This is a really interesting problem, and there's a few interesting things you can do to solve it.

First, you should know that `drawImage` can accept a Canvas, not just an image. The "sub-Canvas"es don't even need to be in the DOM. This means that you can do some compositing on one canvas, then draw it to another. This opens a whole world of optimization opportunities, especially in the context of isometric tiles.

Let's say you have an area that's 50 tiles long by 50 tiles wide (I'll say meters for the sake of my own sanity). You might divide the area into 10x10m chunks. Each chunk is represented by its own Canvas. To draw the full scene, you'd simply draw each of the chunks' Canvas objects to the main canvas that's shown to the user. If only four chunks (a 20x20m area), you would only perform four `drawImage` operations.

Of course, each of those individual chunks will need to render its own Canvas. On game ticks where nothing happens in the chunk, you simply don't do anything: the Canvas will remain unchanged and will be drawn as you'd expect. When something does change, you can do one of a few things depending on your game:

1. If your tiles extend into the third dimension (i.e.: you have a Z-axis), you can draw each "layer" of the chunk into its own Canvas and only update the layers that need to be updated. For example, if each chunk contains ten layers of depth, you'd have ten Canvas objects. If something on layer 6 was updated, you would only need to re-paint layer 6's Canvas (probably one `drawImage` per square meter, which would be 100), then perform one `drawImage` operation per layer in the chunk (ten) to re-draw the chunk's Canvas. Decreasing or increasing the chunk size may increase or decrease performance depending on the number of update you make to the environment in your game. Further optimizations can be made to eliminate `drawImage` calls for obscured tiles and the like.
2. If you don't have a third dimension, you can simply perform one `drawImage` per square meter of a chunk. If two chunks are updated, that's only 200 `drawImage` calls per tick (plus one call per chunk visible on the screen). If your game involves very few updates, decreasing the chunk size will decrease the number of calls even further.
3. You can perform updates to the chunks in their own game loop. If you're using `requestAnimationFrame` (as you should be), you only need to paint the chunk Canvas objects to the screen. Independently, you can perform game logic in a `setTimeout` loop or the like. Then, each chunk could be updated in its own tick between frames without affecting performance. This can also be done in a web worker using `getImageData` and `putImageData` to send the rendered chunk back to the main thread whenever it needs to be updated, though making this work seamlessly will take a good deal of effort.

The other option that you have is to use a library like pixi.js to render the scene using WebGL. Even for 2D, it will increase performance by decreasing the amount of work that the CPU needs to do and shifting that over to the GPU. I'd highly recommend checking it out.

Answer (score 1):

I know that [GameJS](http://gamejs.org/) has blit operations, and I certainly assume any other html5 game libraries do as well (gameQuery, LimeJS, etc etc). I don't know if these packages have addressed the specific array-bounds-checking concern that you had, but in practice their samples seem to work plenty fast on all platforms.

You should not make assumptions about what speedups make sense. For example, the GameJS developer reports that he was going to implement dirty rectangle tracking but it turned out that modern browsers do this automatically---[link](http://twitter.com/#!/gamejs/status/189635929751814144).

For this reason and others, I suggest to get something working before thinking about the speed. Also, make use of drawing libraries, as the authors have presumably spent some time optimizing performance.

I have no personal knowledge about this, but you can look into the appMobi "direct canvas" HTML element which is allegedly a much faster version of normal canvas, [link](http://www.appmobi.com/index.php?q=content/directcanvas-accelerates-html5-game-performance). I'm confused about whether this works in all browsers or just webkit browsers or just appMobi's own special browser.

Again, you should not make assumptions about what speedups make sense without a very deep knowledge of web browser internal processes. That webpage about "direct canvas" mentions a bunch of things that slow down canvas-drawing: "Reflowing text, mapping hot spots, creating indexes for reference links, on and on." Alpha-blending and array-bounds-checking are not mentioned as prominent causes of slowness!

Comment: I'm a GameJs commiter. `blit` is just doing drawImage() underneath. But you are right: don't make assumptions about performance. Browsers are smart and JS compilers are even smarter :)

Comment: In my javascript map editor, I have lags when I even just draw rectangles and lines. Can't imagine `drawImaging` all around the map.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no way around the alpha composition overhead.  Clipping may be one solution, but I doubt there would be much, if any, performance gain.  Not to mention how complicated such a route would be to implement on irregular shapes.

When you have to draw the entire display, you're going to have to deal with the performance hit.  Although afterwards, you have a whole screen's worth of pre-calculated alpha imagery and you can draw this image data at an offset in one **drawImage** call.  Then, you would only have to individually draw the new tiles that are scrolled into view.

But still, the browser is having to redraw each pixel at a different location in the canvas.  Which is quite expensive.  It would be nice if there was a method for just scrolling pixels, but no luck there either.

One idea that comes to mind is that you could implement multiple canvases, translating each individual **canvas** instead of redrawing the pixels.  This would allow the browser to decide how to redraw those pixels, in a more native way,  at least in theory anyway.  Then you could render the newly visible tiles on a new, or used/cached, canvas element.  Positioning it to match up with the last screen render.

But that's just my two blits... I mean bits... duh, I mean cents :]